# phpmyadmin config file location in plesk

Tags: phpmyadmin, plesk

in Plesk I know phpmyadmin location is:

```
/usr/local/psa/admin/htdocs/domains/databases/phpMyAdmin
```

but I cant find the config file and in this location config file is default and sample and its not real config file

```
config.sample.inc.php
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

config.sample.inc.php this file is a template.
To enable custom settings for phpMyAdmin just copy this file to config.inc.php in phpMyAdmin top level directory `/usr/local/psa/admin/htdocs/domains/databases/phpMyAdmin` :

```
# cp /usr/local/psa/admin/htdocs/domains/databases/phpMyAdmin/config.sample.inc.php /usr/local/psa/admin/htdocs/domains/databases/phpMyAdmin/config.inc.php
```

Keep in mind that settings in this custom config will override the defaults that are set in `/usr/local/psa/admin/htdocs/domains/databases/phpMyAdmin/libraries/config.default.php` and some predefined features like auto-login from Plesk will be unavailable, customize it with caution.